# Problem jumping in Swordigo

Tags: swordigo

Does anyone know how to high jump in the snowy slopes, such as in the image below? [image]

Comment: Did you tag the correct game?

Comment: have you tried megaman style jump ? 

btw you should check your game name

Comment: This is Swordigo not summoners war

Answer (score 1):

In order to reach the highest point you need to have unlocked the Dragon's Grasp spell. It acts as a sort of grappling hook and will latch on to that bright purple blob you see in the top right of the image.

If you have the spell, try doing a double jump, then activate the spell to fly up to the blob. Then you can do another jump to make it the platform.

See [here](http://swordigo.wikia.com/wiki/Spell) for a list of the spells and where you can get them if you are having trouble finding it.

This is what it says about the Dragons Spell:

**SPOILERS**

> This spell is used to grapple to the unknown things resembling purple
>   blobs located on various ceilings. This can also be used to pull
>   enemies to you, dealing a minimal amount of damage depending upon the
>   level of the enemy you are fighting.
>
> Unlike your magic bolt, Dragon's Grasp cannot be reflected by enemies
>   at all.
>
> This spell is not required, but is very useful in defeating the third
>   gatekeeper of the third shard of the Mageblade.
>
> This spell is gained in the Fiery Depths.